# Bootstrap input button group addon, show first button with round corner after second button is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a button group where I hide the second button at runtime.

But the first button now as a 90° border. How do I modify the following sample in order to get button 1 show with a round border.

If I hide "button 2" the

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
   $("#btn2").show();
});
$("#btn2").click(function() {
   $("#btn2").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group col-md-6">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button id="btn1" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button 1</button>
    <button id="btn2" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle a class to hide and to also control the radius:

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
   $("#btn1").removeClass('hide');
});
$("#btn2").click(function() {
   $("#btn1").addClass('hide');
});
```

```css
button.hide + button {
  display:none;
}
button.hide {
  border-top-right-radius: .25rem!important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .25rem!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group col-md-6">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button id="btn1" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button 1</button>
    <button id="btn2" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do :

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
  $("#btn2").show();
  $("#btn1").removeClass("myBorder");
});
$("#btn2").click(function() {
  $("#btn2").hide();
  $("#btn1").addClass("myBorder");
});
```

```css
.myBorder {
  border-top-right-radius: .25rem!important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .25rem!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="input-group col-md-6">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button id="btn1" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button 1</button>
    <button id="btn2" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'd create a class and then add and remove it depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You're fighting against bootstrap by trying to modify the nth button border. Here's the style that you're fighting against:

```
.input-group>.input-group-append:last-child>.btn:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle), .input-group>.input-group-append:last-child>.input-group-text:not(:last-child), .input-group>.input-group-append:not(:last-child)>.btn, .input-group>.input-group-append:not(:last-child)>.input-group-text, .input-group>.input-group-prepend>.btn, .input-group>.input-group-prepend>.input-group-text {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

Instead of applying custom CSS and fighting bootstrap, you might be better off removing the item from the DOM instead of hiding it.

```js
var btn = $("#btn2"), parent = btn.parent()
$("#btn1").click(function() {
   btn.appendTo(parent)
});
$("#btn2").click(function() {
 btn.detach()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group col-md-6">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button id="btn1" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button 1</button>
    <button id="btn2" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a comparison of the speed of the answers: https://jsperf.com/show-detach-css2.

Code is not only about performance; it should also solve a problem in the simplest way. When you adopt a display framework like Bootstrap you are adopting it's opinionated styles and fighting against an opinion never ends up being simple.

Comment: Am I wrong, or the CSS method is showing the best performance? (I never used jsperf before)

Comment: Yes CSS is and will always be fastest by far.